# write certain rows from csv file into a new one using R programming

Tags: r, csv

my csv file (test) contains many rows and columns `(header=T)`. I would like to copy  certain rows (24 twos apart) into a new csv file (test1) using R (e.g. if I started with 2nd row, I want rows 2,26,50,74.....,410). Similarly, copy rows (8,32,56...etc) to newer file (test2) and rows (12,36,60..etc) to newer file (test3). I wonder if anyone can help me?

My test code (not working with intense manual labor):

```
export=test[c("2","26","50"),]
write.csv(export,file="test1.csv")
```

Comment: You can try `test[seq(2, nrow(test), 24), ]` and so forth....

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, how to perform that?

Comment: Gopala, thanks your code works, but does not write the results in a new file.

Comment: @Gopala after the 2 now, it SKIPS a row (e.g. 2, 27,51,75..etc) but labels them as (2,26,50,74..etc).

Comment: @Gopala write.csv(test[seq(1,nrow(test),24),],file=sprintf("testss.csv"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this (if i understood your question; the code is untested but might work with some luck)

```
df <- read.csv(....)
splitter <- rep(1:24, NROW(df)/23)[1:NROW(df)]
dfs <- split(df, splitter)
mapply(function(x,y) write.csv(x,y), dfs, paste0(1:length(dfs), ".csv")
```

Comment: lebatsnok, this work...and more. It creates files starting from row 2 to 24 at 24 steps apart! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@RichardScriven did answer my question too, but the answer was erased and I would like to recognize his answer (it did not give the exact solution, worked with a minor tweak).
His solution:

```
x=c(2,8,12)
nr=nrow(test)
for(i in seq_along(x)){
write.csv(test[seq(x[i],nr,24),],file=sprintf("test%s.csv",i))
}
```

it was skipping a row, so I only changed the first line to 
x=c(1,7,11)
and it works like a charm.
Thank you Richard,lebatsnok and Gopala